# Solving $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos{(\sin{x})}-\cos{x}}{x^2}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

My friend got this limits question on his midterm exam that neither I nor did anyone in his class that I asked was able to solve it without using L'Hôpital's rule.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos{(\sin{x})}-\cos{x}}{x^2}$$

I tried using all the trigonometric identities I know of, but it always comes back to the original form. How would we go about solving such a problem? Keep in mind that it's a Mathematics 1 course.

Comment: **Hint**: $\cos\alpha - \cos\beta=-2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$.

Comment: In fact the numerator is asymptotic to $\frac16x^4$.

Answer (score 5):

I would say
$$
\frac{\cos{(\sin{x})}-\cos{x}}{x^2}
= \frac{\cos{(\sin{x})}-\cos{x}}{\sin x - x}
\cdot \frac{\sin x - x}{x^2}
\to 0 \cdot 0 = 0
$$
Here I assume you already know the limit $\frac{\sin x - x}{x^2} \to 0$.

And $\frac{\cos{(\sin{x})}-\cos{x}}{\sin x - x} \to \cos'(0)$ could be from the mean value theorem.

Comment: The last part about using mean value theorem is really nice. +1

Answer (score 4):

As a lemma, you can show that :

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2}=-\frac12$$Indeed :
$$\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t^2}=\frac{1-\cos^2(t)}{t^2(1+\cos(t))}=\frac{1}{1+\cos(t)}\left(\frac{\sin(t)}t\right)^2\underset{t\to0}{\longrightarrow}\frac12$$

Now :

$$\frac{\cos(\sin(x))-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^2\frac{\cos(\sin(x))-1}{\sin^2(x)}+\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$$

By composition of limits and as a consequence of the lemma :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(\sin(x))-\cos(x)}{x^2}=1\times\left(-\frac12\right)+\frac12=0$$

Answer (score 3):

I think a useful strategy in such cases is to express the function in terms of its Taylor series expansion. The Taylor series expansion for cosine function is:

$$\cos{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \ldots$$

We can substitute $\sin{x}$ and $x$ into the Taylor series expansion of $\cos{x}$ to obtain the expansions for $\cos{(\sin{x})}$ and $\cos{x}$. Then, we subtract the expansion of $\cos{x}$ from $\cos{(\sin{x})}$ and divide the result by $x^2$. We can then evaluate the limit as $x$ approaches 0.

For $\cos{(\sin{x})}$ the Taylor series expansion becomes:

$$\cos{(\sin{x})} = 1 - \frac{(\sin{x})^2}{2!} + \frac{(\sin{x})^4}{4!} - \frac{(\sin{x})^6}{6!} + \ldots$$

For $\cos{x}$ the Taylor series expansion remains the same:

$$\cos{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \ldots$$

Subtracting the expansion of $\cos{x}$ from $\cos{(\sin{x})}$ and dividing by $x^2$, we get:

$$\frac{\cos{(\sin{x})} - \cos{x}}{x^2} = \frac{1 - \frac{(\sin{x})^2}{2!} + \frac{(\sin{x})^4}{4!} - \frac{(\sin{x})^6}{6!} + \ldots - (1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \ldots)}{x^2}$$

Simplifying the expression, we get:

$$\frac{\cos{(\sin{x})} - \cos{x}}{x^2} = -\frac{(\sin{x})^2 - x^2}{2!x^2} + \frac{(\sin{x})^4 - x^4}{4!x^2} - \frac{(\sin{x})^6 - x^6}{6!x^2} + \ldots$$

As $x$ approaches 0, $\sin{x}$ also approaches 0. Therefore, the limit as $x$ approaches 0 becomes:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos{(\sin{x})} - \cos{x}}{x^2} = -\frac{0 - 0}{2! \cdot 0} + \frac{0 - 0}{4! \cdot 0} - \frac{0 - 0}{6! \cdot 0} + \ldots = \frac{0}{0}$$

But $\frac{0}{0}$ is indeed undefined.

So we need to go with each expression and check it.

For the first expression we have:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -\frac{(\sin{x})^2 - x^2}{2!x^2} =  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -(\frac{(\sin{x})^2}{2!x^2} - \frac{x^2}{2!x^2})= -(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(\sin{x})^2}{2!x^2} - \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{2!x^2}) = -(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sin{x}}{x})^2 - \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2})$

We know that $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$ so:

$-(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sin{x}}{x})^2 - \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2})=-(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2})=0$

Let check for the second expression now:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(\sin{x})^4 - x^4}{4!x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(\sin{x})^4}{4!x^2} - \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^4}{4!x^2}= \frac{1}{4!} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(\sin{x})^4}{x^2} -\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{4!} = \frac{1}{4!} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} ((\frac{\sin{x}}{x})\sin{x})^2 - 0 = \frac{1}{4!}(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (\frac{\sin{x}}{x})\sin{x})^2 = \frac{1}{4!}(1\times 0)^2=0 $

So the second expression is also 0. Other expressions are also zero so:

$$0+0+\ldots$$

So, the limit of the given function as $x$ approaches 0 is 0.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner and faster to substitute the power series for $\sin x$ in $\cos(\sin x)$.